# Do we need to add the regularization loss into the total loss in tensorflow models?

Tags: tensorflow

In the model definition, I used the `kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=0.00001)` into the `tf.layers.conv2d()` to regularize the convolution kernels in each convolution layer.

My question is: to compute the total loss of the whole network for some batch inputs, do we need to manually add the regularization loss as follows:

```
reg_losses = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
reg_constant = 0.01  # Choose an appropriate one.
loss = my_normal_loss + reg_constant * sum(reg_losses)
```

And if yes, how to determine the `reg_constant` above? What's the relationship between the `scale` and the `reg_constant`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right.

You technically do not need `reg_constant`. You can control each layer regularization by the `scale` param, which can be the same for all layers. In this case you can just set `reg_constant=1`.

The only advantage of using `reg_constant` I see over `scale`, multiplying the regularization loss by `reg_constant`, is perhaps readability of your code.

If you're using a standard architecture I suggest to start with setting `reg_constant=1` and set `scale` to some small scalar, say 0.001. If you have the resources, a better approach is to apply grid search to find the value that empirically minimizes your validation loss, i.e in [0.0001, 0.1].

If you suspect of a layer which should be specifically regularized, you can follow the first case only set that specific layer `scale` for a different value. Apply grid search like before only this time over the two different scale values.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your answer! Yeah, if I understood correctly, the `reg_constant` might be the global multiplication factor for weight decay, and the `scale` is the local factor weight decay for each weight in each layer (e.g. convolution, fully-connected). Just similar to the way in `caffe`. Yeah, you're absolutely right, grid search is needed to select these hyper-parameters. It is really difficult to select each local decay factor for every layer, especially for those very deep networks. And how to initialize the weights is also very important. So difficult...